# My h2 div act weird

Tags: html, css, web-inspector

Okay so, I am curently making a site from scratch and, I have a probleme I REALLY don't understand...

So, I made a nav, a slider, and a `h2` title at the very beggining of my section below. I can't make apply margins to `<h2>NOS SERVICES</h2>`.

The reason? Well, my code says I want to place `h2` with a margin top of 5%;
My html seems okay and w3c validated. But when I look at the inspector, and pass over my `h2` div, it seems to start at the begining of my slider until below my `h2` div.

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?
I really don't understand...
Thanks!

I'll join my code and two screens for you to understand better...

[See my h2 and what the inspector says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oiqld.png)

[and now, my html where the slider is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/squFO.png)

```css
/*ajout des polices*/
@font-face{
    font-family : "Roboto";
    src : url('./fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf');
}
@font-face{
    font-family : "RobotoBold";
    src : url('./fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf');
}
@font-face{
    font-family : "RobotoThin";
    src : url('./fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwsome';
  src: url('./fonts/fontawsome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('./fonts/fontawsome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  src: url('./fonts/fontawsome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  src: url('./fonts/fontawsome-webfont.otf') format('otf'),
  src: url('./fonts/fontawsome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}

/* keframes du site */
@keyframes sliding {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  25% { left: 0%; }
  50% { left: -100%; }
  75% { left: -100%; }
  100% { left: - 200%; }
}

/* style globaux */
body
{
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

h2
{
 font-size: 2em;
 font-family: "RobotoBold", sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
}

h1
{
 font-family: "RobotoBold", sans-serif;
 font-size: 2.5em;
}

/* navigation */
nav
{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-around;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.mainmenu
{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 list-style: none;
 align-items: center;
}

.mainmenu-item
{
 margin: 0 15% 0 0;
}

.mainmenu a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
}

.mainmenu a:hover
{
 border-top: 3px solid #62a8d0;
}

/* slider */
div#slider
{
 width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 25px 25px #999999;
}

.innerslider
{
 position: relative;
 width: 500%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 left: 0;
 text-align: left;
 animation: 13s sliding infinite;
}

.innerslider img
{
 width: 20%;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.fa-chevron-left
{
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 42%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.8em;
}

.fa-chevron-right
{
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 top: 42%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.8em;
}

.fa-chevron-left:hover, .fa-chevron-right:hover
{
 font-size: 2em;
}

.slidertext
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 8%;
 color: #fff;

 width: 40%;

}

.iconeseparateur
{
 width: 5%;
 margin: 0;
}

.separateur
{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.fa-circle
{

 color: #62a8d0;
}

#services
{
 top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Web Agency : l'agence de tout les projets!</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./responsive.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fonts/css/fontawsome-all.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Twitter Card data -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="La WebAgency" />
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="WebAgency agence de developpement de projets, site web, application mobile." />
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />

  <!-- Open Graph data -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="WebAgency" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="Website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://web-tool-box.com//openclassrooms/projets/webagency/webagency.html" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="WebAgency agence de developpement de projets, site web, application mobile" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="166523113967779"/>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./webagency_images/images/ico/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

 <!-- entête -->
  <header>
   <!-- menu -->
   <nav>
    <img src="./webagency_images/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
    <ul class="mainmenu">
     <li class="mainmenu-item"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
     <li class="mainmenu-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
     <li class="mainmenu-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li class="mainmenu-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    
   </nav>

  <!-- slider -->
  <div id="slider"> <!-- carrousel-->
    <div class="innerslider">
     <img src="./webagency_images/images/slider/bg1.jpg" alt="Images Slider1">
     <img src="./webagency_images/images/slider/bg2.jpg" alt="Images Slider2">
    </div>
    <div class="slidertext">
     <h1><span style="color:#62a8d0">WEBAGENCY</span> : L'AGENCE DE TOUS VOS PROJETS!</h1><br>
     <p style="font-size: 2em;">Vous avez un projet Web? La WebAgency vous aide à le réaliser!</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></div>
     <div class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="barfill">
     <div class="fill">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>

  <!-- section 1 -->
  <section id="services">
   <h2>NOS SERVICES</h2>
   <div class="separateur"><hr class="iconeseparateur"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><hr class="iconeseparateur"></div>
    <p>Nous proposons les meilleurs services et en plus, aux meilleurs prix!! Nous avons une équipe de professionnels tous prêt à accueillir votre projet et lui donner vie selon vos souhaits. N'hésitez pas à nous contacter pour un devis, un projet web ou pour un magasin web. Les éléments pris en charge par l'UX vont de la partie commerciale à l'accessibilité.</p>
    <img src="./webagency_images/images/main-feature.png" alt="Image Mac">

    <h3>UX Design</h3>
     <p><b>U</b>ser e<b>X</b>périence : son rôle à pour but de faire la liaison entre l'interface construite, et l'utilisateur. Il est chargé de rendre l’expérience d'utilisation fluide, simple, intuitive, de faciliter l'utilisation de l'utilisateur, de réfléchir pour lui à tout ces moyens là d'avoir la meilleure expérience possible sur son support. Faites confiance à nos équipes pour tout mettre en oeuvre pour avoir l'interface parfaitement en accords avec vos attentes!</p>

    <h3>UI Design</h3>
     <p><b>U</b>ser <b>I</b>nterface : son rôle est là pour rendre accessible, optimale et facile, l'accès et l’exécution des dispositifs liés à l'interface des applications et machines. Nos professionnels sont là pour vous assurer la meilleure expérience possible!</p>

    <h3>SEO</h3>
     <p><b>S</b>earch <b>E</b>ngine <b>O</b>ptimization : son rôle est d'optimiser au mieux le référencement des outils web, d'un site... Le travaille se fait sur les mots clés, la sémantique, l'étude de la concurrence, du marché actuel et doit être fait régulièrement pour mettre à jour les données importantes au référencement. Soyez assuré que votre site sera toujours référencé au mieux et que les clés du référencement seront mises à jours régulièrement par nos services! </p>

  </section>

  <!-- section 2-->
  <section id="projets">
   <h2>NOS PROJETS</h2>
   <div class="separateur"><hr class="iconeseparateur"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><hr class="iconeseparateur"></div>
   <div class="row1"></div>
   <div class="row2"></div>
   
  </section>

  <!-- pieds de page -->
 <footer>

  <form method="post">
     <h2>Contact Info</h2>
     <h4>WebAgency SAS<br /> 25 rue d'Hauteville 75010 Paris<br /> Tel : 01 02 03 04 05</h4>
     <input type="text" name="Nom" placeholder="Nom"><br/>
     <input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail"><br />
     <input type="text" name="Sujet" placeholder="Sujet"><br />
     <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Votre message" style="height:250px"></textarea><br />
     <p class="button2" style="width: 50%">Envoyer</p>
    </form>

  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d2624.221424608057!2d2.3476369159354156!3d48.87305530762753!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sfr!4v1525109889241"  height="800" style="border:0; opacity: 0.7;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by removing that `.slidertext` class from the `div` which contains the `h1`. That class has `position: absolute` which takes the element out of the document flow, and also some other settings which really don't make sense in that context. Then go on from there....

```css
/*ajout des polices*/

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url('./fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RobotoBold";
  src: url('./fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RobotoThin";
  src: url('./fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwsome';
  src: url('./fonts/fontawsome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('./fonts/fontawsome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), src: url('./fonts/fontawsome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), src: url('./fonts/fontawsome-webfont.otf') format('otf'), src: url('./fonts/fontawsome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}


/* keframes du site */

@keyframes sliding {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: - 200%;
  }
}


/* style globaux */

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: "RobotoBold", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "RobotoBold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}


/* navigation */

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.mainmenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.mainmenu-item {
  margin: 0 15% 0 0;
}

.mainmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.mainmenu a:hover {
  border-top: 3px solid #62a8d0;
}


/* slider */

div#slider {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 25px 25px #999999;
}

.innerslider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  animation: 13s sliding infinite;
}

.innerslider img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.fa-chevron-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 42%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.fa-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 42%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.fa-chevron-left:hover,
.fa-chevron-right:hover {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.slidertext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 8%;
  color: #fff;
  width: 40%;
}

.iconeseparateur {
  width: 5%;
  margin: 0;
}

.separateur {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fa-circle {
  color: #62a8d0;
}

#services {
  top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Web Agency : l'agence de tout les projets!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./responsive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fonts/css/fontawsome-all.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Twitter Card data -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="La WebAgency" />
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="WebAgency agence de developpement de projets, site web, application mobile." />
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />

  <!-- Open Graph data -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="WebAgency" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="Website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://web-tool-box.com//openclassrooms/projets/webagency/webagency.html" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="WebAgency agence de developpement de projets, site web, application mobile" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="166523113967779" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./webagency_images/images/ico/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- entête -->
  <header>
    <!-- menu -->
    <nav>
      <img src="./webagency_images/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
      <ul class="mainmenu">
        <li class="mainmenu-item"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
        <li class="mainmenu-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li class="mainmenu-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="mainmenu-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>

    <!-- slider -->
    <div id="slider">
      <!-- carrousel-->
      <div class="innerslider">
        <img src="./webagency_images/images/slider/bg1.jpg" alt="Images Slider1">
        <img src="./webagency_images/images/slider/bg2.jpg" alt="Images Slider2">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1><span style="color:#62a8d0">WEBAGENCY</span> : L'AGENCE DE TOUS VOS PROJETS!</h1><br>
        <p style="font-size: 2em;">Vous avez un projet Web? La WebAgency vous aide à le réaliser!</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="barfill">
        <div class="fill">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- section 1 -->
  <section id="services">
    <h2>NOS SERVICES</h2>
    <div class="separateur">
      <hr class="iconeseparateur"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
      <hr class="iconeseparateur">
    </div>
    <p>Nous proposons les meilleurs services et en plus, aux meilleurs prix!! Nous avons une équipe de professionnels tous prêt à accueillir votre projet et lui donner vie selon vos souhaits. N'hésitez pas à nous contacter pour un devis, un projet web ou
      pour un magasin web. Les éléments pris en charge par l'UX vont de la partie commerciale à l'accessibilité.</p>
    <img src="./webagency_images/images/main-feature.png" alt="Image Mac">

    <h3>UX Design</h3>
    <p><b>U</b>ser e<b>X</b>périence : son rôle à pour but de faire la liaison entre l'interface construite, et l'utilisateur. Il est chargé de rendre l’expérience d'utilisation fluide, simple, intuitive, de faciliter l'utilisation de l'utilisateur, de réfléchir
      pour lui à tout ces moyens là d'avoir la meilleure expérience possible sur son support. Faites confiance à nos équipes pour tout mettre en oeuvre pour avoir l'interface parfaitement en accords avec vos attentes!</p>

    <h3>UI Design</h3>
    <p><b>U</b>ser <b>I</b>nterface : son rôle est là pour rendre accessible, optimale et facile, l'accès et l’exécution des dispositifs liés à l'interface des applications et machines. Nos professionnels sont là pour vous assurer la meilleure expérience
      possible!</p>

    <h3>SEO</h3>
    <p><b>S</b>earch <b>E</b>ngine <b>O</b>ptimization : son rôle est d'optimiser au mieux le référencement des outils web, d'un site... Le travaille se fait sur les mots clés, la sémantique, l'étude de la concurrence, du marché actuel et doit être fait
      régulièrement pour mettre à jour les données importantes au référencement. Soyez assuré que votre site sera toujours référencé au mieux et que les clés du référencement seront mises à jours régulièrement par nos services! </p>

  </section>

  <!-- section 2-->
  <section id="projets">
    <h2>NOS PROJETS</h2>
    <div class="separateur">
      <hr class="iconeseparateur"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
      <hr class="iconeseparateur">
    </div>
    <div class="row1"></div>
    <div class="row2"></div>

  </section>

  <!-- pieds de page -->
  <footer>

    <form method="post">
      <h2>Contact Info</h2>
      <h4>WebAgency SAS<br /> 25 rue d'Hauteville 75010 Paris<br /> Tel : 01 02 03 04 05</h4>
      <input type="text" name="Nom" placeholder="Nom"><br/>
      <input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail"><br />
      <input type="text" name="Sujet" placeholder="Sujet"><br />
      <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Votre message" style="height:250px"></textarea><br />
      <p class="button2" style="width: 50%">Envoyer</p>
    </form>

    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d2624.221424608057!2d2.3476369159354156!3d48.87305530762753!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sfr!4v1525109889241" height="800" style="border:0; opacity: 0.7;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did, but didn't solve my problem... My code is clean, but the inspector says my h2 contains the slider. The inspectors also says that my slider is not in my header. Then it also says the opposite : my slider is at the right position, and my h2 too. Really weird...